# LG G3 режим отладки через usb (не могу установить драйвер)

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, usb, драйвер

***Windows 7 x64, телефон - lg g855, версия Android - lollipop 5.0.***
Подключаю через родной USB cable, методом PTP со включенным режимом отладки для того чтобы пользоваться телефоном как эмулятором в андроид студио.
При первой индефикации телефона установка дравера не проходит успешно, выскакивает окно

> (Программное обеспечение для устройства не было установлено  (LGE
>   Android Phone отказ)).

При попытке обновить драйвер в ручную (на скачанный с офф сайта LG или Google usb driver) через диспечер устройств (В нем устройство находиться под знаком вопроса в вкладке "Другие устройства"->"LGE Android Phone") пишет

> "Не удалось найти драйвер для этого устройства"

(путь указан верно), при попытке обновить через Автоматический поиск драйверов пишет

> "Система Windows обнаружила драйверы для этого устройства, но при
>   попытке установки этих драйверов произошла ошибка"

и ниже в этом-же окне-

> "Эта операция требует интерактивного оконного терминала"

При выключенном режиме отладки телефон подключается к компу нормально, но андроид студио его не видит.

Надеюсь на подсказку знающих, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: У меня G2 . На компьютере установлен LG United Mobile Driver ( из вкладки "Обновление ПО") и LG PC Suite (из вкладки "PC SYNC" ) что находятся на  станице поддержки продукта для моей модели на офф.сайте LG. На телефоне режим MTP. Все работает - и AS его видит и команды adb он выполняет.  Если не поможет, то проблема у вас все равно однозначно в драйвере, обратитесь  на 4pda, в [раздел прошивки](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=616815) вашего устройства, там наверняка есть информация, как подключить устройство в режиме adb, да и сам драйвер тоже.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пролбовал уже, не помогло. В режиме отладки usb pc suite не видит телефон

Comment: Через MTP тоже заработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить драйвера от `Google` следующим образом:

1. Установить `Google USB Driver` из `Android SDK Meneger`
2. Проверить на устройстве отладку по `USB`
3. Заходим в `Device Manager` -> выбираем наше не устройство `Android`-> открываем свойства -> детали -> выбираем из списка `Hordvare Ids` и
   копируем нижнее(меньшее) значение
4. Ищем и изменяем файл `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.txt`, добавляя описание нашего устройства и вставляем значение из пункта 2, по примеру в разделы `x64` и `x86`(либо определить архитектуру смартфона и поместить только в один соответствующий раздел)
5. В `Device Manager` делаем установку драйвера из указанной выше папки

Вот как примерно должно выглядеть описание вашего устройства в файле `android_winusb.txt`:

> [Google.NTx86] или [Google.NTamd64]
>
> ;Название телефона
>
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, (значение из пункта 2 без
>   символов после &)
>   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, (значение из пункта 2)
>
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, (значение из пункта 2 без
>   символов после &)
>   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, (значение из пункта 2)

Также есть немного другое описание установки драйверов на [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver)

Comment: Google USB driver гарантировано работает только для Google Nexus устройств и подмена айдишников других моделей не всегда решает проблему, а иногда приводит к нежелательным результатам. У всех более-менее известных производителей выпущены собственные adb-драйвера, которые просто работают, без всяких шаманств в конфигах. Данные манипуляции еще приемлемы для беззвестных китайских моделей, но для таких, как LG не вижу никакого смысла в столь мудреных манипуляциях против драйвера от производителя.

Comment: лично я очень много раз так устанавливал драйвера, почти всегда все работало отлично и не было никаких нежелательных результатов.

Comment: iamtihonov, спасибо за ответ, все очень понятно, драйвер проинсталировался, только андроид студио не видит телефона.